# Are newly gained items considered Bequests in Haunt 94: Last Will and Tournament?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill, betrayal-widows-walk

This question is spoiler-free.

In Haunt 94: Last Will and Tournament, what is considered a Bequest? Is it just the item and omen cards that we start the Haunt with? Or is it also any items and omens that we gain afterwards?

We had played where we thought it was any item and omen, since the rule book was a bit ambiguous. However, this resulted in a stalemate and we gave up as we went into our third hour of play time. Basically, we gained items far faster than we could get rid of them. So we are unsure if we were playing correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [secrets of survival tome](http://custserv.wizards.com/images/Ops/answer_2365/BaHH_WW_SecretsSurvival.pdf):

> Each hero draws an item card, then each counts
>   his or her total number of item cards and omen
>   cards that can be traded or stolen. (A card that can
>   be traded but not stolen, or vice versa, counts. For
>   example, the Armor and Blood Dagger count, but the
>   Bite doesn’t.) These cards represent your Bequests,
>   which will change as you gain and lose cards.

Especially that last part is interesting for your question: **These cards represent your Bequests,
which will change as you gain and lose cards**

This means that every omen and item card which fits the previous description you gain will become a bequest, if you lose one they will stop being a bequest.

for other confusions: [read this](http://custserv.wizards.com/images/Ops/answer_2365/Widow's%20Walk%20FAQ%20KB%2012.6.161.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think that this is correct, but it kind of makes the scenario unplayable. We started out with 6 Bequests between ourselves and it quick ballooned to 14. Since the heroes win by having the traitor have no bequests, and you reroll for the traitor whenever the traitor has less bequests than another person, we got caught in a stalemate.